# How to set up a VM gateway/DHCP and virtual network in CentOS KVM?

Tags: networking, virtualization, dhcp, linux-kvm, clearos

Today I have a working setup where the physical host runs W2k3.
It has 2 physical NIC's.
It runs Vmware server and I have a ClearOS VM installed acting as a FW/DHCP/DNS for both the host and all the other computers on my LAN.

The External physical NIC has a static IP (1.1.1.1) and is host only for the External NIC (configured as DHCP) in ClearOS VM. The ClearOS VM gets an address from my ISP.

The Internal physical NIC (configured as DHCP) is bridged to the Internal NIC (static) in ClearOS VM. The ClearOS is running a DHCP server on its internal network and provides both the Internal physical NIC in the host with an address and also the rest of the network connected to the same Internal physical NIC.

I now want to migrate to new hardware with a less resource hungry host OS (CentOS 6.4 with a minimal Gnome installation).

How would I get the above setup working in a CentOS/KVM (qemu) environment?

If You please could advice me how to set up the virtual network so it works the way in my new Linux setup I would be more than happy.

I'm looking for something like [this](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=131155).